# How to show Downshift suggestion inside Dialog with Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, z-index, material-ui

I'm trying to set a downshift component inside a dialog body component, playing with zIndex doesn't work, and suggestion always appears underneath.

[image]

Is there a way to show downshift suggestion on top while using with a dialog ?

Here's a dialog with a downshift component inside (taping "a" inside "search a country" show the hidden suggestion) as an example of this issue :
https://codesandbox.io/s/q3lllwr08j

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also faced a similar problem. Hope this is what you are looking for: [codeSandboxLink](https://codesandbox.io/s/vj7696xr77)

I just added a class and added it to `Dialog` and `DialogContent`. The class name is dialogPaper. Look for the class in styles.

The class is:

```
dialogPaper: {
    overflow: "visible"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Find an easy way to fix by just setting dropdown css by position: fixed

Answer (score -1):

I guess the problem is not with the Z-Index. It's just not enough space to show the content of the dialog. I tried this [solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/jnx364mqjv) with wrapping the content of the dialog with Paper element and set the height and width

Comment: The problem is I don't have a choice in my use case. Here it's just a demonstration of the problem using downshift.

Comment: Do you mean anything you use inside a Dialog always gets a lesser zIndex?

Comment: I guess so ... I'm afraid the Dialog and Downshift component is working doesn't allow the suggestion part to be on top and the only way will be to have the suggestion to be anchored directly to the body (like tooltip)